# Spring Security blocks anonymous requests even with @PreAuthorize("permitAll()")

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-security

I have a lot of API endpoints that need authenticated requests, and a few that are allowed for any request. I would like Spring Security to block anonymous requests by default, but to let me overwrite it:

```java
aHttpSecurity.authorizeRequests().anyRequest().authenticated()

...

@PreAuthorize("permitAll()")
@RequestMapping("/foobar")
public ResponseEntity<FooBar> get() {
  ...
}
```

Unfortunately, this does not work: `/foobar` outputs 401. Any idea how to do?

Comment: `aHttpSecurity.authorizeRequests().anyRequest().authenticated()` This will block the request before it gets to the annotated method!

Comment: @AliDehghani Yes, that is what I noticed as well, the question is: how to change this behavior so that `@PreAuthorize` has a higher priority?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Spring Security has two levels of Security.

Filter Level and Method Level.

Filter Level would work with URL and If a URL is not configured to be accessed it will be denied access with 401 or 403 accordingly. This is handled by [FilterSecurityInterceptor](http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/3.2.8.RELEASE/apidocs/org/springframework/security/web/access/intercept/FilterSecurityInterceptor.html)

Method Level is often used as a second level of defense to Authorize who can access a method and what operations or objects he/she can manipulate. This is handled by [MethodSecurityInterceptor](http://docs.spring.io/autorepo/docs/spring-security/3.2.1.RELEASE/apidocs/org/springframework/security/access/intercept/aopalliance/MethodSecurityInterceptor.html)

Answer (score 3):

`@PreAuthorize` is just an annotation which wraps method to check if user can execute annotated method. It works not just with controllers.

When you have http requests, firstly requests go through some spring security filters and when you write `.anyRequest().authenticated()` you just do not go to some wrapped controller endpoint.

So, If you have a few endpoints you can exlude it

`aHttpSecurity.authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers(HttpMethod.GET, "/foobar/**").permitAll() 
                .antMatchers("/**").authenticated()`

and delete `@PreAuthorize("permitAll()")`